# signed maximum detector vhdl

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, vhdl

Sorry I've asked a similar question but I didn't get a answer so I posted this question

I'm currently designing a maximum detector in VHDL which is part of my homework.
The whole system consists of a data generator, data processor and a cmd processor. What I am currently doing is the data processor.

The data processor receive a 12bit BCD signal from cmd processor and request a certain amount of random 8 bit SIGNED binary byte from a data generator corresponding to the BCD signal's value, then it need to find out the maximum and output the a 56-wide set of lines that contain the 7 bytes comprising the peak in the middle
(i.e. bit indices 31 down to 23), and the 3 bytes either side of it. 
picture below is showing the block diagram.[image]

I wrote a process like this to find out the maximum and its location in the array but I don't know how to deal with the signed data. Therefore I'm asking for some advice to refine the code or to rewrite another one that is able to recognize signed bytes

[image]

Comment: Please post the code as text in the question using the MarkDown syntax. And please post also the declarations of all used signals. I recommend, to implement the maximum finder in a separate VHDL entitiy. Your question might be easier to answer, if you give us the interface and protocol of such an entity. The VHDL package `numeric_std` provides a data type `signed` for calculations on signed binary numbers.

Comment: Please post your code and not a screenshots.

Comment: @MartinZabel Hi I just updated it.

Comment: @Paebbels Sorry I can't upload code directly because my school will consider it as plagiarism if they find the my code on internet.

Comment: Plagiarism tools may find your code even in the image , if they have enough OCR capabilities. The only way to get out of the plagiarism problem is to ask a more general question, e.g.: How do I compare two signed binary values in VHDL?

Comment: @MartinZabel :( Fair, if they find this and consider it as plagiarism, I would be in trouble, but did you mean that I should use the package STD_LOGIC_SIGNED? I just wondering if the compiler is 'smart' enough to recognize the sign of each number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the questions in the comments:

> ... but did you mean that I should use the package STD_LOGIC_SIGNED?
>
> I just wondering if the compiler is 'smart' enough to recognize the sign of each number?

The compiler is smart enough if you use the correct data-types. A `std_logic_vector` is just an array (vector) of `std_logic` values (bits).
This vector has no sign. If you use `signed` instead of `std_logic_vector`, the compiler knows that it is treating signed numbers.

Do not use the `std_logic_arith` and `std_logic_signed` packages from Synopsys. They have been super-seeded by the now VHDL Standard package `numeric_std`. This package defines the data type `signed` alongside with relational operators like `<`, `<=`, `=`, `/=`, `>`, `>=`.  Both operands in the comparison can be of different length, the shorter operand will be sign-extended first.

You can convert from `std_logic_vector` to `signed` with:

```
signal x : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); -- 8 bit for example
signal y : signed(7 downto 0);

y <= signed(x);
```

and back

```
signal y : signed(7 downto 0);
signal z : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); -- 8 bit for example

z <= std_logic_vector(y);
```

Of course, you can also use variables instead of signals (using the `:=` assignment).

---

For example, to find the maximum value in an array of signed numbers, you can do:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity maximum_finder is
end maximum_finder;

architecture behavioral of maximum_finder is
  type array_of_signed is array(natural range <>) of signed(3 downto 0);
  signal signed_numbers : array_of_signed(0 to 2) :=
    ( 0 => "0000",  --  0
      1 => "0001",  --  1
      2 => "1111"); -- -1

  signal maximum : signed(3 downto 0);
  
begin  -- behavioral

  process(signed_numbers)
    variable tmp : signed(3 downto 0);
  begin
    tmp := "1000";                      -- smallest number = -8
    for i in signed_numbers'range loop
      if signed_numbers(i) > tmp then
        tmp := signed_numbers(i);
      end if;
    end loop;  -- i
    maximum <= tmp;
  end process;

end behavioral;
```

Of course, this does not actually solve your homework. You have to adapt it, to avoid plagiarism.